# Subquery Factoring recursive sql

Tags: sql, oracle, recursive-query

Im having an issue where im using  recursive subquery factoring to use the previous rows values as my next rows values. Problem is i need to stop using the previous rows values if my product_key changes.

```
        CREATE TABLE MAKE_IT_WORK
    (
      PRODUCT_KEY    NUMBER,
      WEEK           NUMBER,
      OPENING_STOCK  NUMBER,
      INTAKE         NUMBER,
      SALES          NUMBER,
      CLOSING_STOCK  NUMBER,
      FORWARD_COVER  NUMBER
    );
    
 Insert into MAKE_IT_WORK  (PRODUCT_KEY, WEEK)
 Values   (1, 1);
Insert into MAKE_IT_WORK   (PRODUCT_KEY, WEEK, INTAKE, SALES)
 Values   (1, 2, 1000, 80);
Insert into MAKE_IT_WORK   (PRODUCT_KEY, WEEK, SALES)
 Values   (1, 3, 70);
Insert into MAKE_IT_WORK  (PRODUCT_KEY, WEEK, SALES)
 Values (1, 4, 90);
Insert into MAKE_IT_WORK (PRODUCT_KEY, WEEK, SALES)
 Values (2, 1, 0);
Insert into MAKE_IT_WORK (PRODUCT_KEY, WEEK, INTAKE, SALES)
 Values (2, 2, 6000, 500);
Insert into MAKE_IT_WORK (PRODUCT_KEY, WEEK, SALES)
 Values (2, 3, 70);
Insert into MAKE_IT_WORK (PRODUCT_KEY, WEEK, SALES)
 Values (2, 4, 350);
```

CURRENT QUERY

```
with master
as(select product_key,week,opening_stock ,intake,sales,closing_stock,forward_cover,row_number()over( order by 1) lvl,product_key-1 pkey
  from make_it_work),
 bdw_knows_best(product_key,week,opening_stock,intake,sales,closing_stock,forward_cover,lvl,pkey) as
(select product_key
       ,week
       ,opening_stock
       ,nvl(intake,0)intake
       ,sales
       ,closing_stock
       ,forward_cover
       ,lvl
       ,pkey
  from master
  where lvl = 1
  union all
  select a.product_key
       ,a.week
       ,case when b.closing_stock < 0 then 0
                else  b.closing_stock
        end opening_stock
       ,nvl(a.intake,0)intake
       ,nvl(a.sales,0) sales
       ,case when nvl(b.closing_stock,0) + nvl(a.intake,0) - nvl(a.sales,0) < 0 THEN 0
            else  nvl(b.closing_stock,0) + nvl(a.intake,0) - nvl(a.sales,0)
        end closing_stock
       ,a.forward_cover
       ,b.lvl +1
       ,a.pkey  pkey
  from master a,
       bdw_knows_best b
 where a.lvl = b.lvl +1
  )
    select product_key,week,opening_stock,intake,sales,closing_stock,forward_cover,lvl,pkey from bdw_knows_best;
```

[image]

**REQUIRED**

When the product key changes from 1 to 2, I need to use the values from Product_Key 2 and not the last records from Product_Key 1.  I need to somehow group the by Product_Key buckets(so to speak).
Any help or ideas would be highly appreaciated

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a recursive CTE. Window functions (the `OVER` clause) will produce the result you want. For example:

```
select product_key, week, opening_stock, intake, sales,
  coalesce(opening_stock, 0)
    + sum(intake) over(partition by product_key order by week)
    - sum(sales) over(partition by product_key order by week) 
    as closing_stock
from make_it_work
order by product_key, week;
```

Result:

```
 PRODUCT_KEY  WEEK  OPENING_STOCK  INTAKE  SALES  CLOSING_STOCK 
 ------------ ----- -------------- ------- ------ ------------- 
 1            1                                                 
 1            2                    1000    80     920           
 1            3                            70     850           
 1            4                            90     760           
 2            1                            0                    
 2            2                    6000    500    5500          
 2            3                            70     5430          
 2            4                            350    5080
```

See running example at [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=82e19e87cdb143432eee49d71d5fa153).

Comment: ..Thanks so much for the feedback. Really appreciate it